# What is "dynamic assignment of an attribute" in python?

Tags: python, terminology

I've used Python sparingly, so maybe I'm just not privy to some verbiage. Someone at a talk today said that they want to avoid "dynamic assignment of an attribute" and didn't provide an example.

I know what dynamically creating an attribute of a class means, but what does dynamic assignment mean? This seems to imply that there's static assignment in python, but python is a dynamically typed language.

Comment: It just means assigning a value to an attribute whose name is a string (either just a string, or something constructed on the fly) instead of having the attribute name in your source, like `setattr(cake, f'{ingr}{id}', 7)` as opposed to `cake.eggs = 7`. It's generally a fantastic way to bake future bugs into your code.

Comment: It sounds like by "dynamic assignment" the original source means "the dynamic the addition of new attributes to an object". That is contrast with defining all attributes up-front, say inside `__init__` or with annotations in the class body. Basically, you should be able to tell what attributes an instance of a class will have just by glancing at the definition.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ah I see. so you mean the attribute in this class was never referenced in the class definition?

Comment: `python is a dynamically typed language` no, the most popular implementation (CPython)'s "language defaults" allow dynamic behaviour. You can use Python (even CPython) as a statically-typed language; for example, adding `__slots__` to base classes will prevent arbitrarily-named attributes from being added to instances, and static typing with mypy and pyright are very prevalent these days (at least in the open-source community).

Comment: @dROOOze no, python is a dynamically typed language by *design*, that is not an implementation detail. `__slots__` doesn't make python any less dynamically typed. Using third-party static analysis tools doesn't make python any less dynamically typed

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga IIRC some Python compilers (such as mypyc) will cause compilation failures if you try to use dynamic behaviour, so I believe dynamic typing is an implementation detail. Not sure how Jython or IronPython behaves.

Comment: @dROOOze that compiles Python code into C extensions (to run on the CPython runtime). That isn't a different implementation of Python. Python is a dynamically typed language. Jython and IronPython behave exactly the same as CPython in this respect, because it is *part of the language*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga mypyc compiling Python code into C extensions isn't the same as compiling Python code into bytecode to run on the CPython runtime; that's already two different semantic interpretations of the same language (Python). Anyway, I've never come across a language specification of Python which mandates that it's dynamically-typed, but I haven't looked to this in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, this means that the attribute itself is created dynamically as a string then assigned to an instance:

```
class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> attr = "some_dynamically_created_string"
>>> setattr(foo, attr, 42)
>>> foo.some_dynamically_created_string
42
```

Comment: oh hmm, I thought they only meant the assignment part and that the attribute was already created. in your example, `attr` is never revealed within the actual `Foo` class definition? that seems hard to read if they just created attibutes like that outside of a class definition

Comment: @roulette01 sounds like a good reason for why they should be avoided! Note, you *cannot* create an attribute without assignment in Python ... attributes *only come into existence when they are first assigned to!*